# A really simple question: How to apply a style to an iframe whose parent tag's id is known?

Tags: css

How to apply a style to an iframe whose parent tag's id is known??

Example:

```
<div id="xyz">
 <iframe ....>
 </iframe>
</div>
```

Is it

```
#xyz.iframe
{
}
```

I'm new to CSS....can any one help on this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#xyz iframe {
}
```

Whereas this:

```
#xyz.iframe {
}
```

would refer to something like `<div id="xyz" class="iframe" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
#xyz iframe
{
}
```

But this is pretty standard CSS, used almost everywhere. You should really read something on CSS.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the dot, dot deenotes that your targeting a class

```
#xyz iframe
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to w3schools.com for CSS and JavaScript. it's concise and to the point. anything may need is there.